# How to validate ngModel value?

Tags: html, angular, ngmodel

how can i validate the ngModel value. i want to check the value is type number or not. if it has fraction numbers then i have to round up the value to the nearest whole number.so is there any way to include validation in html and where i can add Math.round().

```
 <div style="display: flex; margin-top: -3px; color: black;" class="dist" *ngIf="travel">
<label><span>Distance</span> <input type="number" value="0" [(ngModel)]="travel.distance" />km</label>
</div>
```

Solution

```
<label><span>Distance</span> <input type="number" value="0" [(ngModel)]="travel.distance" (change)="call()" />km</label>

call(){
travel.distance = Math.round(travel.distance);
}
```

Ps: Have updated my solution now i am getting the result which i am expecting. please check. is this the best way to do this or any other solution?

Comment: If you put it in an angular form, you can use one of the built in validation functions or write your own

Comment: As mentioned by @sinanspd refer this https://angular.io/guide/form-validation and use inbuilt validation or create your own logic

Comment: Do you want the value in the input to be rounded up as the value is entered, or do you just want to validate it later?

Comment: @KurtHamilton yes , i want to check if it has any fractions then round it up. i have updated my question please check

Answer (score 0):

you can use addEventListener for get value of input with js and if use angular, you can use (keydown.enter) and like this events for get value